# Reading Multiple files in a while loop in bash, where one file is multicolumn

Tags: bash, file-io, while-loop

There are many posts one how to read from more than one file in bash.

`paste` provides one solution, and other solutions exist as well.

However, what I have not found is the following.

If one has a 2 column text file, one can read each column into a variable like so

```
while read COL1 COL2; do
    echo $COL1 $COL2
done < "$TARG_FILE"
```

If I want to read from two files of the same length in the same loop, how can I `read` the two columns of the first file, and the 1 column of the other file, all in one loop?

Another solution would perhaps be to concatenate the two files before reading, but in principle I would like to know how to read two files with different numbers of columns at the same time.

Comment: Just put a second `read` statement inside the loop (you may have to split the file descriptors, i.e. have one read from &1 and one from &3). Or better yet, use `awk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this if you want to name all the fields individually:

```
while read f1_col1 f1_col2 f2_col1; do 
    :
done < <(paste file file2)
```

or you can read all the fields into an array

```
while read -a all_columns; do 
    :
done < <(paste file file2)
```

or you can read fields from corresponding lines into separate arrays

```
exec 3<file1
exec 4<file2
while read -u 3 -a file1_cols && read -u 4 -a file2_cols; do
    :
done
```

or, I'm sure there are many other possibilities.